# Quadratic regression - spline interpolation

Tags: regression, curve-fitting, spline, linear-interpolation

I am experimenting with a open source code, which is based on learned index for DBMS indexing. Each index is considered as a model which predicts the position of the key in the dataset. I am trying to fit a quadratic regression model in place of linear regression. For the linear regression function of form y=ax+b, the spline connects points (xmax,ymax) and (xmin,ymin). x is the key value and y is the predicted position.CDF of position of keys is in the range of [0,1].

`//Fitting linear spline`

```
`if (mdl_->a_ <= 0) {` 
   `mdl_->a_ = (y_max_ - y_min_) / (x_max_ - x_min_);`
   `mdl_->b_ = -static_cast<double>(x_min_) * mdl_->a_; + y_min_`
 `}`
```

`//Temporary model by in the range of CDF[0,1]`

```
 `T min_key = values[0].first;`
 `T max_key = values[num_keys - 1].first;`
 `root_->mdl_.a_ = 1.0 / (max_key - min_key);`
 `root_->mdl_.b_ = -1.0 * min_key * root_node_->mdl_.a_;`
```

I suppose that in the temporary model, they have fitted ymin for 0 and ymax for 1. And I would like to find the coefficients of a quadratic function, by fitting a spline. Could someone please tell me whether how I could fit a quadratic spline using 2 points (min and max points)?

I tried using the interpolation formula.
[Quadratic spline interpolation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZpOw.png)

The predicted positions fit the parabola if the key values (x) are given sequentially. If the key values are given in random manner, the coefficient (c in ax<sup>2</sup>+bx+c) comes as very larger value which results in segmentation fault. And also the predicted positions don't fit the quadratic curve.

Comment: This is not really a SO question. You are asking a library suggestion and mathematical question in one. On SO please provide example code of what you have tried.

Comment: To be fair, the question may not be C/C++ related, nor even code related, but it is on a subject that shares a lot of maths with Computer Graphics, which is mostly written in C.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to attach the code. I shall add it

Comment: I am sorry for not framing the question properly. I am new to stack overflow.

Answer (score -2):

> Could someone please tell me whether how I could fit a quadratic spline using 2 points?

It is inherent to the maths of quadratic splines that you need four points, or two points and two vectors, to define a quadratic spline.
The definitive text for this is [Computer Graphics : Principles and practice](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Computer-Graphics-James-Foley/dp/0201609215)

The most common interpretation for this problem is known as a [Bezier Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#:%7E:text=A%20B%C3%A9zier%20curve%20%28%20%2F%20%CB%88b%C9%9Bz.i.e%C9%AA%20%2F%20BEH-zee-ay%29,designing%20curves%20for%20the%20bodywork%20of%20Renault%20cars.). It works by injecting two new points (known as control points) per pair of existing points. Each control point is calculated using the vector from each point, to the previous/next point. If there is no previous/next point, the control points are the just the points themselves. So with just two points, the Bezier-curve, is just a line. You will be using a complex way of getting what you already have.